# Python Caplog not capturing custom logger but capturing default logger

Tags: python, unit-testing, logging, pytest, python-logging

I have a custom logger, logging to stdout set at level `DEBUG`

```
class MyLogger(Logger):
    def __init__(self, name):
        super().__init__(name)
        stdout = StreamHandler(sys.stdout)
        stdout.setLevel(10)
        self.addHandler(stdout)

class Foo:
    def __init__(self):
        self.log = MyLogger(__name__)
```

The logger works with the below example:

```
f = Foo()
f.log.debug("Test logger")
```

This prints `Test logger` to stdout

I am trying to do some unittesting and using caplog to assert that certain logs occur. Like below:

```
def test_fetch(caplog):
    f = Foo()

    with caplog.at_level(logging.DEBUG):
        f.log.debug("Test logger again")
    assert "Test logger again" in caplog.text
```

**This test fails** since caplog is empty at the assert statement (or anywhere else). The same test with the standard logger however, passes:

```
def test_fetch(caplog):
    # f = Foo()
    with caplog.at_level(logging.DEBUG):
        logging.getLogger(__name__).debug("Test logger again")
    assert "Test logger again" in caplog.text
```

**Why is this happening?**

Comment: Because your custom logger isn't part of the logger hierarchy. Why do you need to subclass the standard logger anyway?

Answer (score 1):

The `caplog` fixture makes use of the standard logging module to capture output. I don't think you will be able to do it this way. You have to implement a capture sink for your custom logging class which will, in turn, propagate logs to the standard logger. You can do something like this (found a similar solution [here](https://github.com/Delgan/loguru/issues/59)):

```py
@pytest.fixture
def caplog(caplog):
    class PropogateHandler(logging.Handler):
        def emit(self, record):
            logging.getLogger(record.name).handle(record)
    handler_id = your_logger.add(PropogateHandler(), format="{message}")
    yield caplog
    logger.remove(handler_id)
```

**Disclaimer**: I haven't tested this.

It's usually not a good idea to implement a custom Logging class (unless you must), better to add your custom handlers to the standard Logging class. Otherwise, it will be quite difficult to interact with loggers used by other python libraries.

Comment: I tested this but got RecursionError for the "handle" call inside emit function. Using caplog.handler directly instead of writing my own class worked for me.

Comment: I can't reproduce this :/ someone can?

Comment: I added a conftest.py file in the the tests folder using caplog (more of followed what's mentioned in the issue in the link provided in the answer). Works.

Comment: @Berchmans, can you post in your example?